# Visual Studio Publish To Azure With Microsoft Identity Platform Error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to publish an asp.net core app from Visual Studio 2022 to an Azure App Service using Azure AD Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication. At the `Microsoft identity platform screen`, its showing an error:

> Failed to add password. Unable to save changes because the credential
> limit has been reached. Please delete a credential and try again.

[image]

I'm not seeing where I can "delete" credentials. I'm also not sure if this is from my Azure App Service, or local machine. I searched my App Service on Azure, but couldn't find anything related to this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine, Below statements are based on our analysis.

We have created an Asp .Net core (in Visual Studio 2022) with managed identity as an authentication type in our local environment.

> I'm not seeing where I can "delete" credentials.
> I'm also not sure if this is from my Azure App Service or the local machine. I searched my App Service on Azure, but couldn't find anything related to this.

- Before publishing the project, if you are configuring the Microsoft identity platform then you see an option to store the secrets in our local environment as shown below.

[image]

If you want to list those secrets in our local machine

Run the following command from the directory in which the project file exists:

```
 dotnet user-secrets list
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

You can  refer to this documentation for more information about  [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2)

- If you want to configure the Microsoft identity platform at the time of publishing you will get an option to store this client secret as Azure App setting

[image]

1. As shown in the above GIF, while creating the secret from vs you will select the app registration to which this client secret needs to append.
2. Once the client secret got created you can check the secret value in the portal by routing to Active Directory > App registrations> select app registration Name(that you choose while creating from vs)  >certificates & secrets.
   you can delete the secret/credentials from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, I found it last night under App Registrations on Azure. MS only allows 2 keys, deleted them both, republished and it worked.